# ¿Como puedo obtener el ID de un objeto en un select multiple?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo un sistema que registra `proyectos` y personas que pueden tener 1..n proyectos, y necesito enviar los `id` de un `select` multiple a una consulta `GetMapping` de java para advertir que una `persona` tiene un proyecto asignado.

```
<el-form-item label="Asignar a:" prop="person">
                <el-select v-model="form.persons" multiple value-key="id"
                v-on:change="getData(person_id)" id="person_id placeholder="Seleccione personal" class="max-input" filterable>
                  <el-option v-for="person in orderedPersons"  
                            :label="person.name +' '+ person.last_name" 
                            :key="person.id" 
                            :value="person">
                  </el-option>
                </el-select>
              </el-form-item>
```

Computado

```
 computed: {
     orderedPersons: function () {
          return _.sortBy(this.persons, 'name')
      },
```

Metodo java `Getmapping`

```
@GetMapping("/person/hasproject/{id}")
public ResponseEntity getIfPersonHasProject(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long person_id) {
    try {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;
        if (!service.findByPersonId(person_id???).isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(new responseMessage(status.value(), null, getLocaleMessage("success.project.exist")));
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(new responseMessage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), e.getMessage(), getLocaleMessage("error.internal_error")));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Metodo de Vue que llama a esa consulta(Mejorado)

```
 methods: {
getData(el id de la persona que selecciono?) {
  this.$axios.get("/person/hasproject/" + person_id ???).then(response => {
               try {
                  notifications_success(response.data.userMessage);
                } catch (error) {
                 notifications_error('La persona no tiene proyectos');
                 }
  });
},
```

En resumen, como puedo pasarle a esa consulta el `id` de la `persona` seleccionada en el `select` multiple

Comment: Quien llama a getData? no podes agregarle un parametro y usar ese parametro?

Comment: Es más como obtienes `this.persons`? Igual para evitar hacer muchas peticiones al server, te conviene devolver también el número de proyectos que cada `person` tiene asignado. Y simplemente haciendo `this.getPersons()` (o como sea) ya tengas ese valor en `person.numProjects`  o `person.projects.length`.

Comment: puedes hacer `getData(id = null){}` y en la cambiar la linea a: `this.$axios.get('/projects/person/' + (id) ? id : '')`

Comment: @JackNavaRow y como le paso el `id` de la persona que selecciono en el `el-select`

Comment: Consulta el valor de form.persons cuando cambia mediante un watch o con el evento @change del select para ver si te da ahí el identificador del valor que acabas de seleccionar

Comment: Así lo tengo con el `v-on:change` , me habia olvidado de editar eso, la cosa es que no se como le paso a la consulta ese id